# How to create Symbolic Link chain in Windows?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

I am trying to create multi-level symbolic links in Windows 8, but only the direct (first level) symlink seems to be working. If I try to use the second level SymLink, i get errors. i have been using the mklink /D < source > < target > command while creating both the SymLinks - first one pointing to target, and second SymLink pointing to the first SymLink.

Do i need to perform some additional steps as well?

Thanks,
Raman

Answer (score 1):

I am running Windows 8.1 and I am able to create a symbolic link to a symbolic link that points to a directory.

In my example below, I have a folder named target.

```
mklink /D link1 target
```

Then I run

```
mklink /D link2 link1
```

I can successfully cd and dir link2, from a non-elevated command prompt.

I ran both in the same elevated command prompt window. It's possible this was fixed in Windows 8.1. If you haven't upgraded, you should.